# Lock multiple rows but get only one row as returned result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I need lock multiple  rows, but get only one row as returned result, for example lock users: 2,4 and 7, but only get data for  user `where id = 2`

Well, as I understood, there is 2 possible ways:

1) run two different queries:

```
-- get user data and lock that row
SELECT some_column FROM users WHERE id = 2 FOR UPDATE INTO my_var;

-- just lock another rows
SELECT some_column FROM users WHERE id IN(4,7) FOR UPDATE;
```

2) Use one query, with CTE and "fake" update, something like:

```
WITH t AS(
    UPDATE users 
    SET some_column = some_column 
    WHERE id IN(2,4,7)
    returning some_column
)
SELECT some_column FROM t WHERE id = 2
INTO my_var;
```

So, which way is more appropriate? or may be there are even better methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CTE, but without real update:

sample table and data:

```
t=# create table su(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into su values(1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT 0 4
```

select for update three key returning one key:

```
begin; 
with l as (select * from su where i in (1,2,4) for update)
select * from l where i = 2;
BEGIN
 i
---
 2
(1 row)
```

attempting to:

```
begin; update su set i=i where i = 1;
```

in a different session waits for the transaction above to complete, while with `where i = 1` does not. and SQL in first transaction returns only `where i = 2`

Comment: CTE is not a subselect, also I don't see why it does not fit your case - rows (2,4,7) are returned to the outer query

Answer (score 1):

The second solution is worse as it executes idle updates. 
If you want to do that in a single query, use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE:`

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT id, some_column
    FROM users
    WHERE id IN(2,4,7)
    FOR UPDATE
)
SELECT some_column 
FROM t 
WHERE id = 2;
```